# User Defined Type (UDT) as parameter in public Sub in class module (VB6)

Tags: vba, vb6, user-defined-types

I've tried to solve this problem, but can't find any solution. I have a UDT defined in a normal module, and wanted to use it as parameter in a `Public Sub` in a Class Module. I then get a compile error:

> Only public user defined types defined in public object modules can be used as parameters or return type for public procedures of class modules or as fields of public user defined types

I then try to move my UDT in the class, declared as `Private`. I get this compile error:

> Private Enum and user defined types cannot be used as parameters or return types for public procedures, public data members, or fields of public user defined types.

I finaly try to declare it as `Public` in the class, and get this compile error:

> Cannot define a Public user-defined type within a private object module.

So is there any way to have a public UDT used as a parameter in a public sub in a class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So is there any way to have a public
>   UDT used as a parameter in a public
>   sub in a class?

In a word, no.  The closest you can come with just Classic VB code would be to create a class that replicates the UDT and use that instead.  There are definitely advantages there, but you're hosed if you need to pass that to, say, an API as well.

Another option is to define the UDT in a typelib.  If you do that, it can be used as a parameter for a public method.

Comment: I think I'm "a little" late, but... I can totally have a public UDT as a parameter of a public Sub (of a class) in my Excel VBA app.

Comment: I'm even later, but... @André Neves I confirm that I can also.  However, the UDT definition cannot be encapsulated as far as I can find out and that's a pitty.

Comment: @Cool Blue, What do you mean by the UDT definition cannot be encapsulated? Both of you are not "late" if you can help me as I am not able to return a public UDT defined in a Code Module from a public function inside a Class Module. Just to clarify, I can not make the function as Friend, as I need to call this from a C# app and it has to be a Public function. Also I cannot pass the UDT as a ByRef parameter to the class function.

Comment: @Karl, how to define the UDT in a typelib? I am new to this, can you explain in a bit detail or post some links?

Answer (score 18):

Just define the sub as `Friend` scope. This compiles fine for me in a VB6 class.

```
Private Type testtype
  x As String
End Type


Friend Sub testmethod(y As testtype)

End Sub
```

From your error messages it appears your class is private. If you do want your class to be public - i.e. you are making an ActiveX exe or DLL and you want clients to be able to access the sub - then just make both the type and the sub Public.

Comment: @MaikenRoskilde not really. The `friend` solution doesn't work in the general case. Making a class out of the UDT is much more flexible: You can then have properties of UDT type etc.

Comment: In VBA, it seems to work but the Locals window shows it with value "<Application-defined or object-defined error>" instead of showing the tree of it

Answer (score 10):

Ok, here's how to do it, if I can get my cat to leave me alone, that is.

In Form1 (with one command button on it):

```
Option Explicit
'
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal dst As Long, ByVal src As Long, ByVal nBytes As Long)
'

Private Sub Command1_Click()
' Okay, this is what won't work in VB6:
'     Dim MyUdt1 As MyUdtType   ' Declare a variable with a publicly defined UDT (no problem).
'     Form2.Show                ' We could have created some object with a class.  This was just easier for the demo.
'           INSIDE OF FORM2:
'               Public Sub MySub(MyUdt2 As MyUdtType)   ' It won't even let you compile this.
'                   Msgbox MyUdt2.l
'                   MyUdt2.l = 5
'               End Sub
'     Form2.MySub MyUdt1                                ' You'll never get this far.
'     Unload Form2
'     Msgbox MyUdt1.l
'
' The following is a way to get it done:
'
Dim MyUdt1 As MyUdtType         ' Declare a variable with a publicly defined UDT (no problem).
Dim ReturnUdtPtr As Long        ' Declare a variable for a return pointer.
MyUdt1.l = 3                    ' Give the variable of our UDT some value.
Form2.Show                      ' Create our other object.
'
' Now we're ready to call our procedure in the object.
' This is all we really wanted to do all along.
' Notice that the VarPtr of the UDT is passed and not the actual UDT.
' This allows us to circumvent the no passing of UDTs to objects.
ReturnUdtPtr = Form2.MyFunction(VarPtr(MyUdt1))
'
' If we don't want anything back, we could have just used a SUB procedure.
' However, I wanted to give an example of how to go both directions.
' All of this would be exactly the same even if we had started out in a module (BAS).
CopyMemory VarPtr(MyUdt1), ReturnUdtPtr, Len(MyUdt1)
'
' We can now kill our other object (Unload Form2).
' We probably shouldn't kill it until we've copied our UDT data
' because the lifetime of our UDT will be technically ended when we do.
Unload Form2                    ' Kill the other object.  We're done with it.
MsgBox MyUdt1.l                 ' Make sure we got the UDT data back.
End Sub
```

In form2 (no controls needed).  (This could have just as easily been an object created with a class.):

```
    Option Explicit
'
Private Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" (ByVal dst As Long, ByVal src As Long, ByVal nBytes As Long)
'

Public Function MyFunction(ArgUdtPtr As Long) As Long
' Ok, this is how we get it done.
' There are a couple of things to notice right off the bat.
' First, the POINTER to the UDT is passed (using VarPtr) rather than the actual UDT.
' This way, we can circumvent the restriction of UDT not passed into objects.
' Second, the following MyUdt2 is declared as STATIC.
' This second point is important because the lifetime of MyUdt2 technically ends
' when we return from this function if it is just DIMmed.
' If we want to pass changes back to our caller, we will want to have a slightly longer lifetime.
Static MyUdt2 As MyUdtType
' Ok, we're here, so now we move the argument's UDT's data into our local UDT.
CopyMemory VarPtr(MyUdt2), ArgUdtPtr, Len(MyUdt2)
' Let's see if we got it.
MsgBox MyUdt2.l
' Now we might want to change it, and then pass back our changes.
MyUdt2.l = 5
' Once again, we pass back the pointer, because we can't get the actual UDT back.
' This is where the MyUdt2 being declared as Static becomes important.
MyFunction = VarPtr(MyUdt2)
End Function
```

And Finally, this goes in a module (BAS) file.

```
    Option Explicit
'
' This is just the UDT that is used for the example.
Public Type MyUdtType
    l As Long
End Type
'
```

Comment: +1 for sheer nuttiness ;-) I trust you in that it will work, but who will use this?

Answer (score 1):

Just Pass the UDT as Reference parametre and it will work. :)

```
'method in the class

Public Sub CreateFile(ByRef udt1 As UdtTest)

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, had my hopes up for this one, but it simply is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message and after checking the application, I found that in the property window for the class, the "Instancing" setting was set to "1 - Private" for the referenced object.  I changed it to "5 - MultiUse" and got the same error message.  I then went back to a version of the project module prior to when I added that referenced object and added it again the project - it defaulted to "1 - Private".  I changed it to "5 - MultiUse" before doing anything else and closed the project to for it to update before compiling.  I re-opened the project, verified it was still set to "5 - MultiUse", then compiled the project and it compiled cleanly without the error message.

When the error message was saying it didn't allow referencing a private object, the object really was private.  Once I declared it not private, and the project module accepted that new setting, it compiled cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Define UDF (public type) in a module:

```
Public Type TPVArticulo
    Referencia As String
    Descripcion As String
    PVP As Double
    Dto As Double
End Type
```

and use `Friend` in class, module o frm:

```
Friend Function GetArticulo() As TPVArticulo
```

Answer (score -4):

The UDT must be declared in a Public Object, like:

```
Public Class Sample

    Public Strucutre UDT
       Dim Value As Object
    End Structure

End Class
```

Comment: That's VB.NET, not VB6, and you've made the class public. That'll only be possible in VB6 if the project is an ActiveX exe or DLL - even then the questioner may not actually want to make the class public.